# someone reversed my app and uploaded it in Google play, How to report this?

Tags: android, google-play

Someone has reversed my **Android** app which took me several months to make, and uploaded it in **Google Play Store**.
   I reported it many times but it seems like nothing is happening, i am getting tired of this.
 
The guy is using my icon and everything i did for my original app, even the description is copied.
   **NOW** he is getting more installs than me, and i cannot do anything.
What do i need to do in this case?

Comment: reported where? always use proguard to make app much more harder to reverse engineer

Comment: @TouhidulIslam most of the time they just replace ad providers and few images if they feel fancy but there's no need to actually decompile and understand the code when all they do is reupload it. OP can just report it to play store admins and hope for the best.

Comment: Try out some of the suggestions from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/6f11r1/my_app_stolen_by_reverse_engineering_tools_and_re/